# Post processing - How should I remove stringing for the smoothest surface?

Tags: post-processing, stringing

On a PLA print where stringing has occurred, what is the best way to remove it during post processing?

Should I simply cut it with a hobby knife and sand the surface or are the better techniques to use?

Comment: If you already have a print you put a lot of time/materials into, then answers to the question as asked should be helpful. But if this is a general question for when it happens, you really should just get to the bottom of why stringing is happening, and fix it. Prints, especially in an easy material like PLA, should not have stringing.

Comment: Tring to fix the stringing too.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hobby knife with a chisel blade (straight edge perpendicular to handle, beveled on one side only).

Apply with beveled edge against workpiece. Raise the handle in small increments while stroking over the flaw until it is entirely removed.  This provides pretty good control to prevent gouging.

Avoid sanding.

This method also works well for removing "ribs" caused by gaps in painter tape applied to print bed.

Comment: Why avoid sanding?

Comment: Sanding tends to dull any gloss on the surface in my experience.  It should be possible to completely remove strings without resorting to sanding.

Comment: Everything is going to be primed and painted, so the surface won't be visible.

Comment: Then don't avoid sanding if it appears it will be helpful.  Usually not necessary if just removing strings.

Answer (score 1):

I pull them off by hand and then a few quick passes with a cigarette lighter works for me.